# How to style the dynamically created html elemnts through jquery

Tags: css, styles

I have created a script as shown below:

```
 $.getJSON('Json.json',function(data){
 $('#output').empty();                          
 var html = '<div class="general">';                    
 html += '<span class="logo">' + data.general.logo+ '</span>';
 html += '<span class="name">' + data.general.name+ '</span>';
 html += '</div>';  
 html +='<ul class="navigation" >'; 
 html +='<li><a href='+data.navigation[0].link+'>'+data.navigation[0].title+'</a></li>';
```

my ques is how would i style these classes in CSS now. also how would i get the ids as currently my taking id values as data.x.id smthing like this.

Answer (score 0):

When you create elements on the go you have to use the `.on()` method. http://api.jquery.com/on/